# How to determine the limiting distribution of a Markov Chain which can only increment up or down a state at every stage?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a random walk Markov chain that has states from $0$ to $N$. The conditions are that when the chain is at $0$, the chain will go to state $1$ with probability $1$. When the chain is at state $N$, it will go to state $N-1$ with probability $1$ as well. However, for everything between, for any other states $k$, the chain will go to $k+1$ with probability $p_k$ and go to $k-1$ with probability $q_k$. I am trying to find the limiting distribution $\pi$. I feel like there is a very easy way to do this due to the structure of the matrix but I keep running into significant calculations. Does anyone see a hint here? Thanks.

Comment: There are various methods of doing this. (Eigenvectors, difference equations, simulation among them.) In order to be helpful we need to know recent topics in the course, and what you have tried. Can you formulate the transition matrix of this chain? This chain is sometimes called a 'symmetrical random walk on integers 0 through N with reflecting barriers at the endpoints'.

Comment: well, my method of attack is to recognize the markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic, hence the stationary distribution is the limiting distribution. From here on, I create the formulas from $\pi = \pi P$, which yields a series of equations, $\pi_0 = \pi_1 q_1$, $\pi_1 = \pi_0 + \pi_2 q_2$, ..., $\pi_{N-1} = \pi_{N-2}p_{N-2}+\pi_N, \pi_n = p_{N-1}\pi_{N-1}$. However, I dont know how to solve so many equations easily.

Comment: This looks like a "birth-death chain," for which an easier set of equations hold.

Comment: Namely, from the "cut set equations" for birth-death chains: $$\pi_0P_{01} = \pi_1P_{10}, \: \pi_1P_{12}=\pi_2P_{21}, \: \pi_2P_{23}=\pi_3P_{32}, \: ... , \: \pi_{N-1}P_{N-1,N} = \pi_N P_{N,N-1}$$ The intuition is that the long term average rate of transitions from state $i$ to state $i+1$ must be the same as the long term average rate of transitions from $i+1$ to $i$. The former is $\pi_i P_{i,i+1}$ and the latter is $\pi_{i+1}P_{i+1,i}$.